# Select only the rows that aren't unique [MySQL]

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to make a query that will check for duplicates, and if I find duplicates I want to be able to update those accordingly.  For example, I have the following data set, how do I only select the 2 rows that have the same value for 'position'?

> ```
> ID          position
> 1           0
> 2           1
> 3           2
> 4           1
> 5           3
> ```

In this example I would select rows 2 and 4 only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t.position, 
    count(t.*) AS count 
FROM table t
GROUP BY position 
HAVING count(position) > 1
```

Should return an a list of positions and their repetition counts.

Edit: Neglected to alias my table

If you want to see the rows that have duplicate positions try:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
    t1.position,
    t2.ID,
    t2.position
FROM table t1
INNER JOIN table t2
    ON t1.ID < t2.ID
    AND t1.position = t2.position
```

This will give you a set of rows (4 columns) where there are duplicates. You will get 1 row for a duplicate, 3 for a triplicate, 6 for a quad, and it increases from that point on.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on Matt S's answer (which is right on), you could use his results and join back to the original table to get the exact rows:

```
select
    id
    ,position
from table t
    join (
        select t1.position
        from table t1
        group by t1.position
        having count(*) > 1
    ) list
    on t.position = list.position
```

Using a CTE or an EXISTS() function in a WHERE clause would make this a little easier to read, but I don't know what MySQL syntactically supports (I'm a T-SQL guy :) ).  This should be ANSI.

Answer (score 0):

Matt S's answer is the way you would generally get what you're looking for. To expand slightly on scottE's answer (and since we're talking MySQL), you could also use group_concat() to pull together the info you're looking for, if the output is pleasing.

```
SELECT group_concat(ID) as 'IDs', position
FROM table
GROUP BY position
HAVING count(position) > 1
```

should return you:

**IDs    |   position** 
2, 4     |   1